# When form validation fails behind CloudFront, user is sent to root rather than back to form

Tags: php, validation, amazon-cloudfront, silverstripe

I have a SilverStripe website running on two servers behind a load balancer, behind CloudFront. Redis stores session information and I have a sync task that syncs all the assets required. All this is working fine.

I have a form that has various required fields. When the form is filled in correctly it works fine and directs the person to the correct place. However if the user misses a field it should redirect back to the form. Instead it redirects them to `/`. If I click back in the browser it takes me back to the form and the correct fields are highlighted that they are missing.

If I test this on my local machine it works as expected. If I fix myself to one of the servers in prod it also works fine, even if I switch between the two servers manually.

I did in my travels realise that I needed to define the load balancer in the `_ss_environment.php` file:

```
define('SS_TRUSTED_PROXY_IPS', 'x.x.x.x/16');
define('SS_TRUSTED_PROXY_IP_HEADER', 'X-Forwarded-For');
define('SS_TRUSTED_PROXY_PROTOCOL_HEADER', 'X-Forwarded-Proto');
```

I also couldn't find where `TRUSTED_PROXY` was defined in the framework so I added

```
define('TRUSTED_PROXY', '1');
```

as well.

However the form is still redirecting to `/` when validation fails.

What is going on? Is there other things that I'm missing to define the LB?

**EDIT**

I've removed CloudFront (LB still in place) and it's now working as expected. I'd prefer to put it back on however I am unsure what is causing the issue. As far as I can tell the only thing that needs to be forward is the PHPSESSID cookie, should there be something else?

Comment: I suspect you *might* also need to include the [CloudFront IP address ranges](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) as "trusted proxy IPs" because CloudFront is also a proxy, and X-Forwarded-For will have an IP for both the balancer *and* one for CloudFront.  Currently, there are 40 IPv4 address blocks assigned to CloudFront, and you would need to add all of them, **if** that is the issue.

Comment: Looking at the SilverStripe docs, I'm not sure that's the issue.  An easy test appear to be to set `SS_TRUSTED_PROXY_IPS` to `*`.  Otherwise, configure CloudFront to forward and cache based on **all** cookies and query strings, and then back off of that configuration until you identify the issue.

Comment: Yeah, might need to do that test. I would suspect I should only need to do the LB as it's the one doing the request and X-Forward-For etc should only have the IP of the client, not CloudFront. I'll do some tests today.

Comment: Not correct.  Everything in the chain is in X-Forwarded-For.  Browser → CloudFront → LB → Instance gives you `X-Forwarded-For: b.b.b.b, c.f.c.f` at the instance, because CloudFront adds the browser b.b.b.b and the balancer adds CloudFront c.f.c.f... and your web server may also append the LB's internal IP to the end, before handing over to the application, depending on its config.  Everything appends the IP of the thing before it.

Comment: Changing `SS_TRUSTED_PROXY_IPS` to `*` hasn't fixed the issue, I'm going to update CloudFront to forward all requests to see if it fixes it. Thanks

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the help, the Referer header was I believe the issue. I suspect the validation does the `redirectBack()` and as the referer didn't exist it just sent it to `/`

Comment: Aha, yes, that definitely could have been it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CloudFront you have to whitelist several headers. For this issue I believe it was the `Referer` header.